# Not able to disable Drop While using CDK Drag and Drop for Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm using Angular version 15, with material UI version 14

For drag and drop I am using material drag and drop
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

I have a table of 3 columns, and I want the functionality, that when I start dragging from 1, I should only be able to drop it in column 2. The drop functionality for column 3 should be disabled. When I drag from column 2, it should only go to column 3, and column 1 should be disabled. And for column 3, Drag functionality should be disabled.

I've tried to use the attribute cdkDropListDisabled to disable a column, but it is disabling the whole list, and I can still drop objects from other columns to the disabled column. I'm not able to drag the objects of the disabled column.

Comment: Impossible without seeing the code. A guess would be to add info about source and check it  on drop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cdkDropListEnterPredicate](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#controlling-which-items-can-be-moved-into-a-container) for that.

> Depending on whether the predicate returns true or false, the item may or may not be allowed into the new container.

You can define a predicate function in your component that checks if the previous column is allowed for the element to enter the new column.